# Системные файлы в андроид

Tags: android, файлы

Мне нужно получить доступ к файлам системы а именно для получении информации.
Файл build.prop достаю таким образом

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/getprop").getInputStream();
```

Мне нужен список остальных файлов или как их прочитать.
Заранее Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls", "\\system\\bin"});
```

Comment: поясните пожалуйста что за выражение "ls", "\\system\\bin"

Comment: `ls` - юниксовая команда для получения списка файлов в каталоге, а `/system/bin` каталог куда смотреть. 

Ну и вопросы у вас... Вы используется `getprop` не зная что это такое?!